# problems with self definition

Tags: python

```
File "clienttest.py", line 3, in <module>
   x = handle.Client()
File "/home/tmac/Handle/handle.py", line 131, in __init__
   Task.CLT_UPDATE:self.__clt_updates,
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute '_Client__clt_updates'
```

my code throws this error when creating an instance but the function exists. It seems to be prepending _Client to it and i cant figure out why

heres the class definition

```
class Client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        #create task q
        self.tasks = Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
        print str(self)
        #create database
        self.database = server.Database()
        self.database.loadconfig()

        #create networking
        self.network = network.Network(self.tasks)

        #put startup tasks
        self.network.cmd_q.put(NetworkCommand(NetworkCommand.CONNECT,('127.0.0.1',self.database.config['Handle']['port'])))

        #create gui
        self.gui = gui.Gui(self)
        #define task handlers
        self.handlers = {
                Task.CLT_UPDATE:self.__clt_updates,
                            ^----The problem seems to be here--------^
                Task.CLT_INPUT:self.__clt_input,
                Task.CLT_LINEUP:self.__clt_lineup
                }

        #define alive flag
        self.alive = threading.Event()
        self.alive.set()

        #setup logging
        logging.basicConfig(level=self.loglvl, filename='client.log', format='%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.log = logging.getLogger('CLIENT')



        def run(self):
            self.network.start()
            self.gui.initscreen()
            while self.alive.isSet():
                try:
                    task = self.tasks.get(True, 0.1)
                    self.log.debug('Got Task: ' + task.stype[task.type])
                    self.handlers[task.type](task)

                except Queue.Empty:
                    pass


        def addtask(self, task):
            self.tasks.put(task)

        def __clt_updates(self, task):
            raise NotImplemented()

        def __clt_input(self, task):
            pack = Packet(Packet.INPUT,task.data)
            self.network.cmd_q.put(NetworkCommand(NetworkCommand.SEND,pack))
            self.log.debug(':[H]Sent Command: ' + task.data)

        def __clt_lineup(self, task):
            self.gui.addline(task.data)
            self.log.debug(':[H]Line Update: ' + task.data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double underscores in Python cause the Python [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) to kick in at run time.  Name mangling will prepend the class name to each method in the class that has a name starting with 2 underscores.  If you want privateish methods without name mangling, use single underscore.

As noted below in the comments, it looks like you also have an indentation problem.  My guess is that you intend to be creating those methods as class members, but as the question has them here, they are actually indented under `__init__`.

Comment: Still I don't see why he can't access those attributes from a `self` reference of the same class?

Comment: @NiklasB. I was answering the one part of his question.  The other is somewhat odd...

Comment: Oh wait, I see something.  Check the indentation.  If it matches what is in the file, then he has those 3 methods `def`ed within `__init__()` instead of within the `class`.  In that case, those methods really don't exist yet when he's assigning them to the dict, and aren't part of self even after they are created.

Comment: Yeah, that's got to be it. T_Mac: You need to fix a lot :)

Comment: BTW, I think that should be your answer. The hint about better using single underscore is great as well, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Well, he does explicitly ask in his question why he's getting the _Client prepended on to the method names.  I added the bit on indentation as well though.

Comment: Oh, I see. But I think primarily he/she wants to get rid of the error ;) Anyway, it's a great answer now.

Comment: thanks for the answer about name mangling, the problem turned out to be the indention. Seems like when your looking for a problem you always look for something difficult and miss the simple things